# I can't access datacontext

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I'm using VS 2010 Ultimate .NET 4.0 in ASP.NET project, I have a DataClassesDataContext in the 
App_Code folder and a customer class in the same folder, which tries to instantiate DataClassesDataContext

```
DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
```

But I'm getting "the type or namespace DataClassesDataContext" could not be found, are you
missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Is it a namespace problem? What namespace are you declaring DataClassesDataContext in? Is your other class in the same namespace / are you importing the DataClassesDataContext namespace? I can't remember how classes declared outside a namespace behave in C#; it's safer to just add one I think.

Comment: Its the problem of Visual Studio, just restart the VS and wait for 2 minutes then reopen and run the solution it shall be fine.

Comment: Go into the designer file, and look at the namespace and context type name.  Try entering in the full path via var db = new MyNamespace.MyDC() and see if that works.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it is somehow related to  both the dbml file and the customer class are both in the App_Code Folder, because when I write  the same line in a webform codebehind, IntelliSense sees it

Comment: ok, it seems it was related to it was missing an using directive and when added VS2010 wasnt refreshing the changes.